# How to correctly access QMap in QAbstractTableModel::data()

Tags: qt, qabstracttablemodel, qmap, qmodelindex

I got a QMap with an identifier and a corresponding object. When subclassing QAbstractTableModel::data() you get a QModelIndex with row and column, respectively. Each row should represent one object (QAbstractTableModel::rowCount() is myMap->size()).

Is it legit to get the current object via

```
myMap->values().at(index.row())
```

Has this implications (sorting, inserting), because the identifiers of the (unsorted) map are by-passed? I mean for QAbstractTableModel::setData() I need to do the same map identifier by-passing?! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quite late answer, but can still be useful:

```
(myMap->constBegin() + index.row()).key();
(myMap->constBegin() + index.row()).value();
```

will do the trick avoiding the copy of `values()` method

Answer (score 0):

When you say "identifier", I assume you mean **key**, and "the corresponding object" is the **value**. `QMap` is by-definition sorted by key.

If you never intend to use the `QMap` key-value functionality, you should consider storing your values in a `QList` container and accessing that based on the row index as you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

`QMap::values` returns all values in ascending order of their keys, so probably your code will work. Still, I'd use something like following:

```
myMap[this->index(index.row(), 0).data().toString()]
```

provided that you call it from QAbstractTableModel, and your keys are in 0th column.